Performance improvement of multiple s.str.split calls
DataFrame has the following columns
NCT Number                            object
Study Title                           object
Study URL                             object
Acronym                               object
Study Status                          object
Brief Summary                         object
Study Results                         object
Conditions                            object
Interventions                         object
Primary Outcome Measures              object
Secondary Outcome Measures            object
Other Outcome Measures                object
Sponsor                               object
Collaborators                         object
Sex                                   object
Age                                   object
Phases                                object
Enrollment                           float64
Funder Type                           object
Study Type                            object
Study Design                          object
Other IDs                             object
Start Date                    datetime64[ns]
Primary Completion Date       datetime64[ns]
Completion Date               datetime64[ns]
First Posted                  datetime64[ns]
Results First Posted          datetime64[ns]
Last Update Posted            datetime64[ns]
Locations                             object
Study Documents                       object
dtype: object

Column interventions.head(10):
0             DEVICE: Kinesio(R)Tape for edema control
1                                       DRUG: Ramipril
2             DRUG: Dexamethasone intravitreal implant
3         DRUG: Nivolumab 480mg and surgical resection
4      OTHER: group 40|OTHER: group 50|OTHER: group 60
5                                          OTHER: Diet
6             DRUG: Triamcinolone|DRUG: Turmeric paste
7    DIAGNOSTIC_TEST: DNA methylation|DIAGNOSTIC_TE...
8                             DRUG: CS0159 (Linafexor)
9    BIOLOGICAL: Short Ragweed Pollen Allergenic Ex...
Name: Interventions, dtype: object


Split on | (but don't expand to new columns, not every element has equal splits)
Explode into new rows
Row-wise split on first : 
Expand into 2 columns

I wrote
interventions.str.split('|',expand=False).explode().str.split(': ', expand=True, n=1)
but am curious if there is a more efficient approach.  Output of cProfile on the single line:
 6314077 function calls (6314057 primitive calls) in 9.940 seconds

   Ordered by: call count

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
1820581/1820567    0.562    0.000    0.562    0.000 {built-in method builtins.len}
   910260    0.549    0.000    0.781    0.000 accessor.py:348(<genexpr>)
   910259    0.496    0.000    0.496    0.000 accessor.py:339(cons_row)
   859697    2.039    0.000    3.210    0.000 object_array.py:354(<lambda>)
   859697    1.115    0.000    1.115    0.000 {method 'split' of 're.Pattern' objects}
   457375    0.390    0.000    0.390    0.000 {method 'split' of 'str' objects}
   457372    0.514    0.000    0.934    0.000 object_array.py:358(<lambda>)
    14021    0.013    0.000    0.013    0.000 threading.py:1196(ident)
     8012    0.005    0.000    0.005    0.000 {method 'keys' of 'dict' objects}
4182/4181    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 {built-in method builtins.isinstance}
     4007    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 {method 'values' of 'dict' objects}
     4006    0.052    0.000    0.097    0.000 ipkernel.py:775(_clean_thread_parent_frames)
     2003    0.021    0.000    0.026    0.000 threading.py:1533(enumerate)
     2003    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 {method '__exit__' of '_thread.RLock' objects}
       45    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.getattr}
       18    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 typing.py:2173(cast)
       17    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 generic.py:42(_instancecheck)
       17    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 generic.py:37(_check)
       16    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.hasattr}
       11    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.issubclass}


For now, each row needs to have a single intervention.
Since each intervention is dict-like, would it be possible to convert each intervention to a dict, and expand that to the new columns?  Obviously trying to perform this vector-wise.

Provide a [mre], please.

It's difficult, but if you want performant pandas-like package I suggest using polars
